# How to display image if the src send as props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `data.js` file, and from that file, I am trying to display some images. Here is my example `data.js` file:

```js
const data = {
  lists: [
    {
      image: "../assets/images/collection/23.png",
    },
    {
      image: "../assets/images/collection/422.png",
    },
  ]
}
```

I send `data` as props at the end, I am trying to display  images like this:

```
<img src={props.item.image} alt={`${props.item.tokenId} image`} />
```

but I see nothing but in the DOM I see this:

```html
<img src="../assets/images/collection/425.png" alt="425 image">
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you are passing a string path value that is processed at runtime when the page content is accessed instead of at build-time. In other words, the path URL is accessed when the app is running and the browser tries to fetch the image asset from the public directory.

Use `require(props.item.image)` to attached the image asset correctly when building the component.

```
<img
  src={require(props.item.image)}
  alt={`${props.item.tokenId} image`}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the images like below, so they are processed by the compiler (Webpack, I assume if you used `create-react-app`):

```
import image23 from "../assets/images/collection/23.png";
import image422 from "../assets/images/collection/23.png";
const data = {
  lists: [
    {
      image: image23,
    },
    {
      image: image422,
    },
  ],
};
```

Or, move `assets` inside the `public` folder and use an absolute path, like so:

```
const data = {
  lists: [
    {
      image: "/assets/images/collection/23.png",
    },
    {
      image: "/assets/images/collection/422.png",
    },
  ],
};
```